# Python syntax, dot before method name

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand the code:

```
x = 1 
size = 16  
for i in range(size):
    print((' ' * (size - i)) + bin(x)[2:]
    .replace('0', '  ').replace('1', ' *'))
    x ^= x << 1
```

How does the dot before `replace` gets applied to the print statement above?

Why does this raise an error?

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
    .replace('1','ONE')
```

The first example prints this:

```
                 *
                * *
               *   *
              * * * *
             *       *
            * *     * *
           *   *   *   *
          * * * * * * * *
         *               *
        * *             * *
       *   *           *   *
      * * * *         * * * *
     *       *       *       *
    * *     * *     * *     * *
   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

I was expecting that the second would print this:

```
0
ONE
2
```

Comment: Count the parentheses. That `.replace` is still *within* `print()`.

Comment: please paste your code properly.

Comment: In the first example the replace is applied to the string inside the print and the second example is invalid

Comment: That's why it's a bad idea to have layout elements as syntax delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

Your code:

```
x = 1
size = 16
for i in range(size):
    print((' ' * (size - i)) + bin(x)[2:]
        .replace('0', '  ').replace('1', ' *'))
    x ^= x << 1
```

More clear by introducing some variables:

```
x = 1
size = 16
for i in range(size):
    spaces = (' ' * (size - i))
    binary = bin(x)[2:]
    print(spaces + binary
        .replace('0', '  ').replace('1', ' *'))
    x ^= x << 1
```

The reason that dot in the beginning of line is not an error is that you have an unclosed parenthesis and Python is looking for remaining parts on the next line.